# Build table in html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to build table in HTML5.
The Requirements of the table are :

1. Allow collapse / expand
2. Highlight selected rows
3. Moues hover changes

What is the best way to bulid table ? ( meaning that it will look good to the users )

Do I need to use in jquery ?

Does there is something special for tables in HTML5 ?

Comment: Why not use CSS? It has all of the above proprieties. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp

Comment: There is a table element. you could use JS instead of jQuery, also i would suggest using CSS, it will allow for the highlighting. you can give a row a class and just make the background a different colour. is this a dynamic table?

Comment: @Flo [w3fools.com](http://http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: what event and where this Allow collapse / expand

Highlight selected rows should happen?

Comment: @Andreas Its a decent starting point, but as any other web related concept, it requires more research so in that sense I do agree with you.

Comment: You could start with the [example on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference/Examples#Example_8:_Using_the_DOM_Table_Interface).

Comment: I didn't tried yet I want to know in which direction it is the best way to do.

Comment: I have table 3*3 and i want for example age and color and count per color when I press on collapse it will hidden all the information on the color and I can see only the count , does there is a plug in for this ?

Comment: I thought that I can use in a plug in or other features of jquery for this , the idea that the table will look the best as possible

Comment: is the size of the table dynamic? also consider using colgroups to hide the columns http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_colgroup_tag.cfm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it's not 100% necessary, I would use jQuery for simplicity and easy cross browser compatibility.

To make your rows expand and collapse, you'll want to set up your table so that each row has a row below it that can be [toggled (hidden/shown)](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) by clicking the row above it.

A quick search brought up [a little jquery plugin that has done this already](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/07/20/Expand-table-rows-with-jQuery-jExpand-plugin.aspx). Even if you don't use it, it might serve as a good example.

Cell highlighting can be done in jQuery. 
Just make it so that [when a cell is clicked](http://api.jquery.com/click/) it [adds a class to it](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) that has the CSS properties you desire.

```
$("td").toggle(function() {
     $(this).addClass("highlight-clicked");
}, function() {
     $(this).removeClass("highlight-clicked");
});
```

[Mouseover events can be done in jQuery too](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/). Very similar to the code above.

```
$("td").hover(function() {
     $(this).addClass("highlight-hover");
}, function() {
     $(this).removeClass("highlight-hover");
});
```

To better demonstrate, [here's a little jsfiddle I whipped up](http://jsfiddle.net/9jStT/1/)

Comment: Actually, the question was how to highlight selected row, not cell.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <input type="button" id="btnExpCol" value="Collapse" />
    <div id="divTest">
        <table id="tblTest">
            <tr>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="Highlight">
                <td>Peter</td>
                <td>Griffin</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="Highlight">
                <td>Lois</td>
                <td>Griffin</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

//===============================================//

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        //$('body').html('<table id="tblTest"><tr><th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th></tr><tr class="Highlight"><td>Peter</td><td>Griffin</td></tr><tr class="Highlight"><td>Lois</td><td>Griffin</td></tr></table>');

        $('#btnExpCol').click(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == 'Collapse') {
                $('#divTest').stop().slideUp('3000');
                $(this).val('Expand');
            } else {
                $('#divTest').stop().slideDown('3000');
                $(this).val('Collapse');
            }
        });

        //$('#tblTest').find('.Highlight').live('click', function () {
        //    $(this).toggleClass('Red');
        //});

        $('#tblTest').find('.Highlight').click(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('Red');
        });

        $('#tblTest').find('.Highlight').live({
            mouseenter: function () {
                $(this).addClass('Blue');
            },
            mouseleave: function () {
                $(this).removeClass('Blue');
            }
        });
    });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nanoquantumtech/UfMq3/)